# Can not find EntityDataSource in my toolbox in VS 2012

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework-5

I am trying to follow an example in creating a Winform to access Database, here is the link of this tutorial
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/221931/Entity-Framework-in-WinForms?msg=4528028#xx4528028xx

But in this tutorial, after adding the datagridview on the form, I can not find the EntityDataSource. What is the problem? I am totally fresh in EntityFramework, so I am not sure whether I did something wrong by following the tutorial?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMpVU.jpg

Another small help, can anyone recommend an example to create an winform to read data from database by using entityframework?

Comment: did you add the component to the form?

Comment: This is the problem, I can not find the component called EntityDataSource

Answer (score 2):

In the ToolBox, right click and select Choose Items... Then find the EntityDataSource control and tick it!

However, note that this control seems to be outdated to the EF5...